# Issue extracting data from Varchar Col using Date Condition

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a `mysql` Db with a `varchar` col (ArrangementDate) and it contains dates:

I am running this query :

```
select * from insolvenceyTestdetailstable 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(  `ArrangementDate` ,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) BETWEEN  '7/5/2009' AND  '26/2/2016' 
and ID > 0 LIMIT 50000;
```

But it returns 0 result when in DB i can clearly see rows as:

```
27/2/2015
9/10/2013 
9/10/2012
```

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be the date format you compare with.

replace `'7/5/2009'` with `2009-05-07` and `'26/2/2016'` with `'2016-02-26'`

you can easy test valid dates by querying it with a select

```
select DATE('2015-02-27') as D1, DATE('27/2/2015') as D2; //D1 valid, D2 null
```

your statement should look like

```
select * from insolvenceyTestdetailstable 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(  `ArrangementDate` ,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) BETWEEN '2009-05-07' AND  '2016-02-26' 
and ID > 0 LIMIT 50000;
```

Answer (score 0):

More format is needed.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c898d1/6

```
select 
    * 
from 
    insolvenceyTestdetailstable 
WHERE 
    STR_TO_DATE(`ArrangementDate`,'%e/%c/%Y') BETWEEN  STR_TO_DATE('7/5/2009','%e/%c/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('26/2/2016','%e/%c/%Y') and 
    ID > 0 
LIMIT 50000
```

Comment: Pls check the sqlfiddle result. I verified with your data and it works as expected. @confusedMind